# Varying paper stocks in perfect-bound book

Tags: paper, binding, ibooks-author

Are there any rules/rhymes to making books with different paper stock within? Aiming to print a book with a few small sections of uncoated stock interposed between coated stock. Is it possible to bind in leafs next to the larger signatures? Does the placement of an uncoated leaf or 4p signature need to mirror somewhere else in the book?

New to bookmaking - thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! This is definitely possible, but it's going to be up to the printer/binder. If they will need to be mirrored, is dependent on the type of binding. Saddle stitching— yes. Perfect binding— no.

Comment: @CircleB - Why not for perfect bound? Admittedly it's been over 30 years since I worked in a bindery, so memory is hazy, but I don't recall us not being able to make books with occasional 'photo plates' on coated stock.

Comment: My comment wasn't clear, I was trying to say that you won't have to have a mirrored page in a perfect bound book, only in a saddle stitched book.